# Hidden information when I try to scrape a web

Tags: php, web-crawler

this is my first question in case of making an error.

when I try to obtain the information of a field, at 30 requests it leaves segmented.
I would like to know why, and how I could obtain the complete information, because if I visualize it manually, the information is not hidden in the html.

This is a small-scale example of what I'm trying

Url: https://empresite.eleconomista.es/MUSEO-VINO-MADRID.html

```php
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://empresite.eleconomista.es/MUSEO-VINO-MADRID.html');

foreach ($html->find('section.wlogo') as $bloc) {

    foreach ($bloc->find('li.ico-cif') as $cif) {
    echo $cif->plaintext.';';
    }
}
?>
```

I try to get the whole information and this happens.

Before the 30 petitions appears like this:

''CIF:[1234564]''

After the 30 requests:

''CIF:[1234...]''

---

I read and I do not know if it has something to do with the '' user_agent ''.

In the terms of use and does not specify anything in the automatic obtaining of the information, in case of asking if my action was inappropriate.

Comment: It's probably loading extra information via Ajax, and your PHP script can't execute the javascript that loads those extra results

Comment: So I can not get it directly from the html?

Comment: Not if the content isn't rendered until a javascript call takes place. You'd have to look at using something else such as a nodejs library that spins up chromium and can also execute the javascript

Comment: So, how is it possible that after the 30 requests I need to represent javascript?